# What to do if laravel doesn't work (error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I downloaded Laravel via composer and started the server using the command `php artisan serve`. After I came to the site (`localhost:8000`), console said:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

and site stopped working.

I tried to delete and download Laravel, but it still doesn't work.

Console:

> `nikita@fatoom-n ~/a $ php artisan serve`
>
> `Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>`
>
> `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`
>
> `nikita@fatoom-n ~/a $`

Why after I come site it soppes working?

Comment: What version of PHP versions are you using? What operating system are you running on?

Comment: linux mint 18.3 php 7.3

Comment: Before anything else try running `composer dump-autoload && composer update && php artisan cache:clear` and then seeing if you can run `php artisan serve` again

Comment: I tried, nothing changed

Comment: In that case I would have a look at: https://laravel.io/forum/05-24-2014-segmentation-fault-with-php-artisan-serve

Comment: Hello, i'm fixed it by reinstalling php7.3

Answer (score 3):

First Run command for auto load, then clear cache and run update.

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
composer update
```

Comment: It should be `composer update`, not `update composer`.

Comment: Thank you, @MBiniek

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue.

I have temporarily disabled xdebug model and started artisan again. It worked.

```
sudo phpdismod xdebug

php artisan serve
```

I will post permanent solution with xdebug running if found.

---

Permanent Solution:
Update PHP to PHP 7.3.1+

[Reference](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27030)

Comment: I reinstalled the operation system and it works. It lagged so much... I think there was a problem in my computer (there was too much junk)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forget about semicolon in my Interface file

```
    interface AuthServiceInterface
    {
        public function logout(): void;//←this semicolon
    }
```

Put it back and all will work

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if anyone will face segfault issue.
This could also cause a circular dependency injection.

```php
ServiceProvider.php

public function register()
{
   $this->app->bind(ClassOne::class, fn() => new ClassOne(new ClassTwo());
   $this->app->bind(ClassTwo::class, fn() => new ClassTwo(new ClassOne());
}
```

At least that is what I removed and segfault issue resolved.